# "Inline assembly" for Java byte codes

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm looking for existing implementations of the following idea: suppose somebody wants to write "inline assembly" byte codes inside a normal Java program (most relevant applications would involve invokedynamic instruction that is not otherwise available in Java). One way to do this would be as follows:

```
void foo(boolean b) {
    Label l1 = Asm.label();
    Label l2 = Asm.label();

    int i = Asm.no_int();
    Asm._const(0);
    Asm.store(i);
    l1.bind();
    Asm.load(i);
    Asm.push(10);
    Asm.if_cmpge(l2);
    Asm.getstatic("java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream");
    Asm.load(i);
    Asm.invokevirtual("java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V");
    Asm.inc(i);
    Asm._goto(l1);
    l2.bind();
    Asm._return();
}
```

Instructions are encoded as API calls, then we'd need to run a normal java compiler, and then to post-process the byte code and replace the API calls with actual instructions.

P.S. I'm aware of ASMifier of the ASM Framework, it does not solve the problem stated above.

Comment: Don't we have the Java Native Interface for this?

Comment: JNI is for interfaces between "native implementations" (made in C, C++), he's asking for "inline bytecode"

Comment: ...oh! Inline bytecode. I thought this was a question about inlining actual assembly language in a Java program.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but isn't it off-topic: *"The question is: do you know of any library/tool that takes this approach?"*.

Comment: Decompilers often emit inline bytecode as comments when they get confused. But that's not quite the same.

Comment: There is a whole stack exchange for patent prior art: http://patents.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about prior art for patents -> belongs on http://patents.stackexchange.com/ which is not a migration option.

Comment: @tcaswell: I do not think that is what he means by "prior art".

Comment: Oh, apparently, the expression "prior art" is to be used for patents exclusively. Is it patented? :) It's not what I meant. I changed the formulation of the question. Thanks

P.S. Patents are terrible evil.

Comment: Does it have to be _truly_ inlined, i.e., with the API calls representing the bytecode of the call site's actual method?  Or would it be sufficient to built a callback (say, an implementation of a functional interface)?  The latter would be far easier and more convenient.

Comment: I think it should be inlined.

Answer (score 6):

`ClassLoader` has a method, [`defineClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)), that lets you dynamically generate a class by providing the bytecode. Combine this with [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or other suggestions from this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291492/which-library-program-can-be-used-to-generate-java-bytecode) question.

Comment: I was looking for _inline_ assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for "prior art" for a patent, I think that the JNode native code compiler did this kind of thing with some methods in its version of the `Unsafe` class.  However, the primitives weren't bytecodes.  Rather they were things that couldn't be expressed as bytecodes.

---

Injecting bytecodes that way doesn't seem like a good idea to me:

- There are better ways to do that; e.g. BCEL.
- It could be tricky (for the programmer) to integrate what the injected bytecodes are trying to do with the rest of the method.  Especially considering that the bytecodes for the rest of the method will depend on what java compiler you are using.
- For Java on a conventional JVM platform, you'd need to do the translation of `Asm` "calls" to bytecodes ... before the class was loaded.  It would then be subject to checking by the verifier.

Comment: Patents are evil. I'm just looking for some implementations of the same idea.